# How to extract values from a list in varying intevals (defined by list)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, extract

I want to extract values from a column in dataframe in varying intervals. The intervals are stored in a list. Is there a way to extract this?

The column looks like this:

```
6211
6111
711
414  
3211  
3311 
3411  
3511 
6211 
6111
...
```

and the list like this:

```
"2"  "4"  "2"  "6"  "15" "2"  "9"...
```

Now I want to apply the list on the column of the df (the list defines the steps between the required values. The result should be stored as a new variable in the df. Due to missing values we need to fill the new column with NAs.These should be stored in the intervalls defined in the list.

So the result should look like this:

```
#    X       Y
1   6211    711
2   6111     NA
3    711     NA
4    414    3411
5   3211     NA
....
```

where the number of NA's between the rows are again defined by the vector.
In a last step I want to paste X and Y together in order to get a key variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` over the vector and subset the column

```
df$x[cumsum(c(1,vec))]
#[1] 6211  711 3411 6211
```

Or if you want it as a column

```
df[cumsum(c(1,vec)), ,drop = FALSE]
```

Or use `slice` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  slice(cumsum(c(1, vec)))

#    x
#1 6211
#2  711
#3 3411
#4 6211
```

**EDIT**

For the updated part to get new column `Y` we can do

```
vals <- df$x[cumsum(c(1,vec))][-1]
df$y <- NA
df$y[cumsum(c(1, vec + 1))] <- vals
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(6211, 6111, 711, 414,3211,3311, 3411,3511,6211,6111))
vec <- as.numeric(c("2","4","2"))
```

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah! This worked very well for me. As you already mentioned I want to store the result as a new variable. Now I get the error:

replacement has 21880 rows, data has 361333

That's obvious, but it is possible to store the extracted data as new variable and fill the rows between the obvervations with 'NA's (again with using the vector)?

Comment: @copamundial how are you trying to store it? What is the code for it?

Comment: ````
Lines$new<-Lines[cumsum(c(1,Vec1)), ,drop = FALSE]
````

Comment: this will not work since you have more number of rows in `Lines` whereas this code will give us values which is less than the number of rows.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion. 

df[cumsum(c(1,vec)), ,drop = FALSE]

Do I need to use cumsum again to assign the extracted data to the right rows?

Comment: What do you mean by right rows? How do you know which is the right row? Your example shows only one column.

Comment: can you update your post with your current dataframe and expected output. It is difficult to understand it in the comments as there is no formatting.

Comment: thank you @RonakShah. Yet it is not quite what I need. After storing the extracted values as new column, I need to shift the position of the values by the vector. So for the first row x=6211 and y=711.

Comment: Your expected output is not clear to me. Why the `Y` column starts with `711` and not `6211` where did the first value go? Why there are 2 `NA`s after 711 and then `3411` appears.

Comment: The first value needs to be dropped. The 2 NAs are there because the first value in the vecor is 2. After this 2 NAs the next value should be printed. Afterwards we need four NAs before the next value is printed.

Comment: @copamundial I have updated the answer, see if it works now for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much @RonakShah! And sorry for my bad explaination. I adapted your suggestion a bit for my case and it worked!

Comment: No problem. I am glad you were able to make it work in the end. :)